# javascript recursion counter

Tags: javascript, recursion

I tried to rewrite this indexOf MDN example  to practice recursion

```
var str = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.';
var count = 0;
var pos = str.indexOf('e');

while (pos !== -1) {
  count++;
  pos = str.indexOf('e', pos + 1);
}

console.log(count); // displays 4
```

This was my solution:

```
var count = 0;

function countLetters(str, p) {
  var pos = str.indexOf(p);
  if (pos == -1) {
    return count;
  }
  else {
    count ++;
    return countLetters(str.substr(pos + 1), p)
  }
}
console.log(countLetters('To be, or not to be, that is the question.', 'e'));
```

It works, but is there anyway to get the count variable  inside the function itself? Is it not really a true recursion if I have a count variable outside the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is to return the count value form the method, so if the item is not found you return 0, else you return `1 + value-of-recursive-call`

```
function countLetters(str, p) {
    var pos = str.indexOf(p);
    if (pos == -1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + countLetters(str.substr(pos + 1), p)
    }
}
console.log(countLetters('To be, or not to be, that is the question.', 'e'));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d12j4vue/)

Answer (score 7):

In a recursive function, if you want to keep a variable around from one "iteration" to the next, then you need to pass it as an argument:

```
function countLetters(str, p, count) {
  count = count || 0;
  var pos = str.indexOf(p);

  if (pos == -1) {
    return count;
  }
  else {
    return countLetters(str.substr(pos + 1), p, count + 1);
  }
}

console.log(countLetters('To be, or not to be, that is the question.', 'e'));
// => 4
```

However, this is not always necessary, as Arun P Johny's answer illustrates.